# Using a recursive function to output the Nth number from fibonacci pattern that has alternating negative numbers (0, 1, -1, 2, -3, 5 ...)

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve a recursive function practice problem using Java and it has me completely stumped:

```
Given the small integer n (0 <= n <= 40) you need to find the n-th number of the alternating Fibonacci sequence.

The sequence starts with 0, 1, -1, 2, -3, 5, -8, 13, -21, ...

So, fib(0) = 0, fib(1) = 1 => fib(2) = -1.
```

I can implement the function to find the Nth fibonacci number, however the specific problem requirements are defeating me. Any time I try to implement some sort of negative number, it ends up screwing up the arithmatic instead of altering the final number that is output. My mind keeps coming back to creating some sort of conditional that only triggers on the top-most frame, but I don't think that is something that can be implemented.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? This is my base function without implementing any sort of the negative number requirements:

```java
    public static long fib(long n){
        if (n == 0){
            return 0;
        } else if (n == 1){
            return 1;
        } else if (n == 2){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return fib(n-2)+fib(n-1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: fib(n-2)-fib(n-1)

Comment: @Lebecca had the correct answer on this, thank you. Such a simple solution, I'm feeling pretty dense at the moment.

Comment: fudge make sure to mark an answer as accepted if it's solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not too late to put this as an answer:

```java
    public static long fib(long n){
        if (n <= 1){
            return n;
        } else {
            return fib(n-2) - fib(n-1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The other answers were great, but this was the true answer. This practice question definitely seemed like more of a puzzle than a practice on execution...

Comment: this is exactly the same than what I answered, but with the multiplications done. I left the constants for explaining purposes

Comment: Don't bother, sometimes simple is beauty. @Daniel

Answer (score 3):

You can simply have another function to deal with the negative requirement:

```
public static int AlternatingFiboonacci(int n){
    if(n > 0 && n % 2 == 0) return -fib(n);     //if n is even and greater than 0
    else return fib(n);
}
```

---

If you need a single working function, this should do the job

```
public static int fib(int n){
    if(n < 2) return n;     
    if(n % 2 == 0) return -1 * (fib(n - 1) - fib(n - 2));
    else return (-1 * fib(n - 1)) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

What this function does is:

- when `n` is even, return `fib(n - 1)` (which is odd, thus positive) - `fib(n - 2)` (which is even, thus negative). The subtraction will be a positive value, that you multiply by -1.
- when `n` is odd, return -1 * `fib(n - 1)` (which is even, thus negative) + `fib(n - 2)` (which is odd, thus positive).

Comment: That was my first inclination, however it needed to be implemented in a single function. Turns out the response above achieved this: fib(n-2)-fib(n-1)

Comment: added the single function requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can first get your number:

```
public static long fib(long n) {
    if ((n == 0) || (n == 1))
        return n;
    else
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

And then add the minus sign if necessary:

```
public long result(long n){
    long fib = fib(n);
    if(n>0 && n%2==0) return -fib;
    else return fib;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just think of the formula for this one.

You want normal Fibonacci sequence but on even position they are negative. Let's say your method will be named altFib. If you apply *Math.abs( altFib(n) )*, you get actual value for n-th Fibonnaci number, so it's obvious that below code will also result with n-th Fibonacci number:

```
int fib_n = Math.abs( altFib(n-1) ) + Math.abs( altFib( n-2 ) )
```

Then you want it to be negative on even positions, so just use simple if else:

```
if( n % 2 == 0 )
    return -fib_n
else
    return fib_n
```